# Accessing listview items

Tags: vb.net, listview, listviewitem

How do I access the items of a listview which in a another form inside a panel.

The Listview is inside a Panel........Panel1

Panel1 is in a Form ..................Form 1

I have another form .........Form2,  from where I want to input items to Listview in Form 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the Form1 listview items from Form2 using this:

```
Form1.ListView1.Items(...)
```

Be careful accessing controls from other forms -- you can accidentally cause events to fire which can make confusing errors. Sometimes it's safer to assign the items to global variables or parameters for use in other forms.